# Filtering data from DB using several links delivered by PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html

**UPDATE**

I've solved by myself this problem. It wasn't a problem at all, just because lack of experience.

Everything went from a misunderstanding of the $_GET variable and for what can be used, and PHP data types as well. When I did read twice the PHP documentation, I understood that it is actually an array and I could put several variables and pass several parameters through it, as it is persistent.

From there, the rest was piece of cake. With a single include and a bunch of functions I can do all the database petitions and output them as I want!

I'm glad I've been able to solve it by myself, and thanks to Passerby, who made me think about how I was managing the $_GET variable.

---

I had to redo this question because last one was a dull brick of text. Let's simplify.

Let's say I have a fruit DB with 'n' items. The cols are the following:

- Name of the fruit.
- Country of origin.
- Color.

On the index.php I have sidebar.php with links and a content.php with some text into it. Like this:

```
<!--html code here-->
<?php include('includes/content.php') ?>
<?php include('includes/sidebar.php') ?>
<!--more html code here-->
```

The links of the sidebar.php are like these:

```
<a href="searchDB.php?value=country">Browse by country</a>
<a href="searchDB.php?value=color">Browse by color</a>

etcetera.
```

searchDB.php is generated with the same layout than index.php with this difference:

```
<!--html code here-->
<div id="content">
<?php include('functions/fruit_list.php') ?>
</div>
<?php include('includes/sidebar.php') ?>
<!--more html code here-->
```

inside fruit_list.php there's a script that shows all countries into the **content** `<div>`
once you click on 'browse by country'. It generates some hyperlinks as well which I'm unable to manage or figure how to link them to a function, or somewhere that allows me to go one level deeper (for instance if you click into 'Japan', I'd like to list all fruits from Japan).

If possible, the new generated list (all fruits from Japan), should be on the same content div.

Any ideas? Thoughts? I have a wrong approach to do this?

Comment: this question is way too verbose. you may want to make it shorter and just get to the point so people will actually read it. as for me, good night sir!

Comment: sure thing! I didn't want to let any loose threads.

Comment: Generally there're two approaches: 1) on sidebar you provide links like `href='searchDB.php?country=japan'`, and in `fruit_list.php` you listen to `$_GET['country']` and generate corresponding content; 2) on sidebar you provide buttons like `onclick='ajax('fruit.php?country=japan')` and modify DOM in `div#content`.

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer. I indeed listen to $_GET['country'] on the fruit_list.php and it generates the first output / further input I need. But I'd like to go manage it just using hyperlinks, and if possible, do it entirely in PHP, without using AJAX.